# What is eq_rect and where is it defined in Coq?

Tags: equality, coq

From what I have read, `eq_rect` and equality seem deeply interlinked. Weirdly, I'm not able to find a definition on the manual for it.

Where does it come from, and what does it state?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use `Locate eq_rect` you will find that `eq_rect` is located in `Coq.Init.Logic`, but if you look in that file there is no `eq_rect` in it. So, what's going on?

When you define an inductive type, Coq in many cases *automatically generates* 3 induction principles for you, appending `_rect`, `_rec`, `_ind` to the name of the type.

To understand what `eq_rect` means you need its type,

```
Check eq_rect.
```

here we go:

```
eq_rect
     : forall (A : Type) (x : A) (P : A -> Type),
       P x -> forall y : A, x = y -> P y
```

and you need to understand the notion of [Leibniz's equality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equality_(mathematics)#Logical_formulations):

> Leibniz characterized the notion of equality as follows:
>   Given any `x` and `y`, `x = y` if and only if, given any predicate `P`, `P(x)` if and only if `P(y)`.
>
> In this law, "`P(x)` if and only if `P(y)`" can be weakened to "`P(x)` if `P(y)`"; the modified law is equivalent to the original, since a statement that applies to "any `x` and `y`" applies just as well to "any `y` and `x`".

Speaking less formally, the above quotation says that if `x` and `y` are equal, their "behavior" for every predicate is the same.

To see more clearly that Leibniz's equality directly corresponds to `eq_rect` we can rearrange the order of parameters of `eq_rect` into the following equivalent formulation:

```
eq_rect_reorder
     : forall (A : Type) (P : A -> Type) (x y : A), 
         x = y -> P x -> P y
```

Comment: Thank you! What about the other two terms that are generated? I assume `_ind` is the induction principle. What is `_rec`?

Comment: Those principles have the same form, the difference between them lies in the type of predicate `P`: for `eq_rect` it's `A -> Type`, for `eq_ind` it's `A -> Prop`, and for `eq_rec` -- `A -> Set`. In fact, `eq_rec` is just a special case of `eq_rect`, which you can check with `Print eq_rec`.

Comment: Note that you can also generate such principles with things like `Scheme eq_rect := Minimality for eq Sort Type`, `Scheme eq_rec := Minimality for eq Sort Set`, `Scheme eq_ind := Minimality for eq Sort Prop`, and there are also dependent versions where you replace `Minimality` with `Induction` and get schemes like `forall (A : Type) (x : A) (P : forall a : A, x = a -> Type), P x eq_refl -> forall (y : A) (e : x = y), P y e`.  I believe Coq automatically chooses `Minimality` for inductives in `Prop`, and `Induction` for inductives landing in `Set` and `Type`.